# Save p-value outputs to a dataframe when the statistical test uses binary variables

Tags: r, statistics, binary, binary-data

I'm currently trying to obtain FDR-corrected p-values from the difference between two groups, and save this p-values for 148 different variables. The two groups are control (rows 1-10), and FAD (rows 11 - 40).
The groups have binary values for the 148 variables, so I'm using fisher.bintest from the RVAideMemoire package for now. I want all the p-values to be saved in a dataframe.

Trying something like:

```
df.stats <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[156:303], function(x) fisher.bintest(x ~ df$Group,alpha = 0.05, p.method = "fdr")))
```

Returns an error `x is not a binary variable`. Traceback:

```
5.
stop(paste(names(mf)[1], "is not a binary variable"))
4.
chisq.bintest(x ~ df$Group, alpha = 0.05, p.method = "fdr")
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2.
lapply(df[156:303], function(x) chisq.bintest(x ~ df$Group, alpha = 0.05, p.method = "fdr"))
1.
as.data.frame(lapply(df[156:303], function(x) chisq.bintest(x ~ df$Group, alpha = 0.05, p.method = "fdr")))
```

Trying something like the following gives the same error:

```
df.stats <- as.data.frame(sapply(X = df[,grep("_bin", names(df),value = T)], FUN = function(x) fisher.bintest(x ~ df$Group, alpha = 0.05, p.method = "fdr"))
```

The function works fine on its own, with one variable:
`fisher.bintest(df$lh_G_oc.temp_med.Parahip_thickness_bin ~ df$Group, alpha = 0.05, p.method = "fdr")`

I'm not necessarily looking for the cleanest solution, just something that can do the above for all 148 variables and put the results in a dataframe. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass in names in `lapply` and construct formula using `reformulate`.

```
df.stats <- as.data.frame(lapply(names(df)[156:303], function(x) 
  fisher.bintest(reformulate('Group', x),alpha = 0.05, p.method = "fdr")))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I gave this a go and got an `Error in eval(predvars, data, env)`, which I could bypass by changing [156:303] to [-156:-303] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539633/error-in-evalpredvars-data-env-object-rm-not-found). The "Group" section returns the same error `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Group' not found`, which I'm not sure how to fix. I've tried df$Group, removing quotations etc. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have column called `Group` in your data? Can you provide small subset of your data in a reproducible format?  Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).